# Looking for a way to distinguish identical string entries for index use

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a function in python 3.5.2 to read chemical structures (e.g. CaBr2) and then gives a list with the names of the elements and their coefficients.
The general rundown of how I am doing it is i have a for loop, it skips the first letter.  Then it will append the previous element when it reaches one of: capital letter/number/the end. I did this with index of my iteration, and then get the entry with index(iteration)-1 or -2 depending on the specifics.  For the given example it would skip C, read a but do nothing, reach B and append to my name list the translation of Ca, and append 1 to my coefficient list.

This works perfectly for structures with unique entries, but with something like CaCl2, the index of the iteration at the second C is not 2, but zero as index doesn't differentiate between the two.  How would I be able to have  variables in my function equal to the value at previous index(es) without running in to this problem? Keeping in mind inputs can be of any length, capitalization cannot change, and there could be any number of repeated values

Comment: The fact that your algorithm doesn't work with CaCl2 (or CaCr03 for instance) suggests that the algorithm isn't really doing the right thing. Since you know that all Chemical Elements start with a capital letter, why don't you split the string into segments which each start with a Capital letter. This could be easily achieved by a regular expression.

Comment: That is true, I realized an alternate solution was to make a counter and use the counter to get the index of the iteration.

Comment: To be honest I am even more confused as to what you are trying to do and what your proposed solution is.  Sorry.

Comment: For example if I want to get the index of the second Carbon in CH3CH2OH I can't do index of the iteration as it will find the first Carbon to be the index.  But if in my for loop I assign a variable which starts at zero, and is increased by one at the end of each iteration, this variable is equal to the index of my iteration always and like so I can use it for different things.